# How to install iTunes on Big Sur?

Tags: itunes, install, big-sur

I want to install iTunes on my macbook. My Macbook is running Big Sur.

The [iTunes website](https://www.apple.com/au/itunes/) is a bit confusing.

[image: iTunes website]

The text says:

> Download macOS Catalina

But then the button to upgrade says

> Upgrade to macOS Big Sur

So is Big Sur supported or not? Why is it telling me to upgrade to Big Sur when I'm already running Big Sur?

This laptop is managed by my employer, and upgrading to Catalina will break unrelated things. So I want to install iTunes without upgrading to Catalina.

The "system requirements" say:

> OS X version 10.10.5 or later

I'm using OS X 11.5. So I meet the requirements.
So where is the download button?

The page says:

> You can always download iTunes 12.8 for previous versions of macOS,

But when I try to download 12.8 and run it, it says:

> This update requires macOS version 10.13.99 or earlier.

I can't find iTunes in the App Store either.

I found [a page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252911872) on the Apple support forum which sounds relevant, but the page won't load. ("Oops! An unexpected error has occured", in Firefox and Safari.)

My Mac:

[image: about my mac]

Comment: **iTunes** is not compatible with **macOS Big Sur**! The last version of **macOS** that supports **iTunes** is **macOS Mojave**.

Comment: Oh. Ok. So on Catalina iTunes has split into multiple apps. They really could have phrased that more clearly. I guess I want Apple Music. So do I need to upgrade to Catalina for that?

Comment: RE: "I guess I want Apple Music. So do I need to upgrade to Catalina for that? " --  You said your are running **macOS Big Sur** and it already has **Music**.

Comment: Yes. I can see the Music app on my Big Sur laptop. The music app mentions the "iTunes Store". So the iTunes *store* still exists, but just not the iTunes *app*?

Comment: RE: "So the iTunes _store_ still exists, but just not the iTunes _app_?" --  The **iTunes** _application_ still exists for versions of **Apple**'s **OS** that support it. The **iTunes Store** is a software-based online digital media store operated by Apple Inc, not the same thing as the **iTunes** _application_.